# PHP Preg match for alphanumeric and symbols

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a project in PHP and I want to make a password check in order to accept strings consisting only of alphanumeric and symbols that the keyboard has. I know for alphanumerics I have to make it like this: `preg_match('/[^a-z_\-0-9]/i', $string);`, but I don't know how to add the symbols.

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you want to do that? You shouldn't care about the contents of my password, just hash it, store it and compare that hash to the hash of my input next time I try to login to your site.